# How to prevent further execution of program till an event completes in as3?

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I intend to collect data using php, but for the time being i'm retrieving the data from an htm file: the code is as follows:

```
var Data:String;
Data=getData("file:///C:/..../try.htm");
trace(Data);

function getData(url:String):String
{

    var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

    phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
    phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
    var a:int=1;
    trace("Worked");


    function showResult (event:Event):void
    {

        import flash.text.*;
        Data= "" + event.target.data.systemResult;
        trace(Data);


    }
return Data;
}
```

Right now the function call executes, adds the event listener, then returns to the main code and tries to trace the variable Data, which results in null, later on when the event completes, it executes the function. What I want is the program control to return only after the completion of the event and the showResult() has executed. Please help

Comment: It seems like you're trying to load your data synchronously. I don't think it can be done, so I'd recommend changing your code around a bit, depending on what you plan to do after.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a synchronous download in Flash. In order to wait for an event, and not use the processing power, use the enter frame listener and a flag. An example:

```
var Data:String;
var weAreReady:Boolean=false;
getData("file:///C:/..../try.htm");
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrame);

function getData(url:String):void
{

var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
}

function showResult(event:Event):void
{
    import flash.text.*;
    Data= "" + event.target.data.systemResult;
    trace(Data);
    weAreReady=true;
}
function enterFrame(e:Event):void {
    if (weAreReady) {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
        goFurther(); // this will be called when the data will be finally ready
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add something to Vesper's answer. There is no point using an EnterFrame since the event is doing the same job. Just wait for the event to get triggered before you do anything else.

```
var Data:String;
var weAreReady:Boolean=false;
getData("file:///C:/..../try.htm");

function getData(url:String):void
{

var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
}

function showResult(event:Event):void
{
    Data= "" + event.target.data;
    trace(Data);
    goFurther(); // this will be called when the data will be finally ready
}
```

In case you wanted to call different requests at the same time and would want to wait for all the events to be triggered, once again avoid adding an EnterFrame or a Timer to the mix. First I would avoid multiple simultaneous requests and would queue them instead, seems better way to control the whole thing. But in the case you'd like to do it anyway, I would write it like that:

```
var Data:String;
var _total:int; //number of events
var _done:int;  //number of events triggered
var weAreReady:Boolean=false;
_total = 4;
_done = 0;

getData("file:///C:/..../try.htm");
getData("file:///C:/..../try2.htm");
getData("file:///C:/..../try3.htm");
getData("file:///C:/..../try4.htm");

function getData(url:String):void
{

var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
}

function showResult(event:Event):void
{
    Data= "" + event.target.data;
    trace(Data);
    if(++_done == _total) goFurther(); // this will only be called when all the events have been triggered
}
```

Comment: Hmm. In this case it will suffice indeed, but in case you're waiting for multiple flags to get set within the respective loaders, an enter frame listener might be the way to go. Thanks, a valuable addition.

Answer (score 0):

In As3.0 only wait function using a while() loop.

see a below post.

[Action Script Sleep function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009929/action-script-sleep-function)

[AS3-sleep-function](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?232714-AS3-sleep-function)

Regretfully no ActionScript/Flash does not have an equivalent to the sleep function.

And I'd recommend change code alike following code.

```
var Data:String;
getData("file:///C:/..../try.htm");

this.addEventListener("received", receivedHandler);
var isReceived:Boolean = false;
function receivedHandler(e:Event):void
{
    isReceived = true;
    trace("Data: ", Data);
    //do stuff
}

function getData(url:String):void
{

    var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

    phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
    phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
    var a:int=1;
    trace("Worked");

    function showResult (event:Event):void
    {
        import flash.text.*;
        Data= "" + event.target.data.systemResult;
        dispatchEvent(new Event("received"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That will cause 100% CPU usage while it's in the wait loop. If you do a `sleep(1)` in the loop it would be much better, but it's still from an ideal solution. What if _data is never set to anything?  And what if it only happens to have partial data at a particular point when it's checked?

Comment: @bitmapdata.com : sorry this might sound stupid but i haven't found a proper wait logic yet :(, any suggestions?

Comment: why down vote?. you well known as3.0? this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009929/action-script-sleep-function also using a while loop in as3.0 only use a while loop other method no available.

Comment: Amendment: I hadn't noticed at first glance that this was actionscript rather than PHP code.  However, polling in a loop without any kind of delay is bad in pretty much every language I've worked with, because as stated above it normally causes 100% CPU usage.  From what I've read on actionscript, it would be better to use an Interval to poll in a loop with a pause.

Comment: Okay, doing it with an event is a much better approach than busy waiting.

Comment: Appreciate your advice. the as3.0 can not control the threads. so can't create asynchronous processing.

Comment: A bit off topic, you can now have multithreading in AS3, using Worker objects, available from FP11. But, making a thread to simply wait in a while(1) loop isn't smart.

Comment: @Vesper where is official adobe docs or spec? i only know using a Timer. [AS3.0 and Multithreading](http://www.as3dp.com/2011/04/actionscript-3-0-and-multithreading-1-defining-the-problem/) also  libspark Thread Library [libspark Thread](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/Thread)

Comment: [Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) Actually, the site is full of AS3 docs.